# how refer to values from form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

Like in title - I've got a tag (no model) based form (form_tag) and I want after submit obtain values entered in fields of that form - how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a form is submitted, such as the one below:

```
<% form_tag do %>
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
<% end %>
```

a `params` hash is set so you can easily access its values in your controller, like so:

```
value = params[:first_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the params hash in the controller, like so:

```
def update
  field_value = params[:field_name_here]
end
```